# Processing non-numeric values in numeric column

Tags: r

I have a spreadsheet with a column name Autonumber below which has maximum values expect for a few values "*"

```
CityName    Autonumber
NYC         2
Atlanta     4
Nashville   8
Boston      6
LA          *
Vegas       3
Florida     *
```

How can I:-

Scenario a) remove rows with "* " values
Scenario b) put average value of Autonumber to replace "*"

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Something like this?
First, I substitute `NA` for `"?"`.

```
df$Autonumber <- as.character(df$Autonumber)
is.na(df$Autonumber) <- df$Autonumber == "?"
df$Autonumber <- as.numeric(df$Autonumber)
```

Now what the question asks for.

```
# 1) remove rows with NA
i <- is.na(df$Autonumber)
df[!i, ]

# 2) replace NA's by mean value
df$Autonumber[i] <- mean(df$Autonumber, na.rm = TRUE)
df
```

**Data.**

```
df <- read.table(text = "
CityName    Autonumber
NYC         2
Atlanta     4
Nashville   8
Boston      6
LA          ?
Vegas       3
Florida     ?                 
", header = TRUE)
```

Answer (score 1):

This question is possibly duplicate, see this link.

[Filter multiple values on a string column in dplyr](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25647470/filter-multiple-values-on-a-string-column-in-dplyr)

Anyway:

- Scenario A

```
library(dplyr)
df # your dataframe

cA <- df %>% 
  dplyr::filter(Autonumber != "?")
```

- Scenario B

```
MAutonumber  <- mean(df$Autonumber)
MAutonumberX <- mean(df$Autonumber, na.rm = T)

cB1 <- df %>% 
  dplyr::mutate(Autonumber = ifelse(Autonumber == "?", MAutonumber, Autonumber))

cB1 <- df %>% 
  dplyr::mutate(Autonumber = ifelse(Autonumber == "?", MAutonumberX, Autonumber))
```

Note that there are several ways to do what you want.

https://stackoverflow.com/a/41588616/9699371

Answer (score 0):

Scenario a and b put together:

```
df[df$Autonumber == "?","Autonumber"] <- mean(df[df$Autonumber != "?","Autonumber"])
```

Make sure that the rest of the numbers are numerical and not factors